# Html elements positioned differently between browsers

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I was doing css on my little project, and I saw some inconsistencies in how some elements are positioned comparing chrome and safari. Here is the photo:

[safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXGkJ.jpg)

[chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUSGy.jpg)

In safari it is how I want it to look.

I've done styling in styled components, here is the code:

```
const HomeZeroStyles = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 85vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;

  .left-content1 {
    min-width: 55%;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
  }

  .behind1 {
    min-width: 75%;
    min-height: 35%;
    outline: 1px solid var(--pall4);
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-right: 40%;
    margin-left: 5%;
  }
  .behind2 {
    min-width: 70%;
    min-height: 30%;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    margin-left: 40%;
    background-color: var(--pall4);
  }
  .behind3 {
    min-width: 75%;
    min-height: 20%;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #881337;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    &:hover {
      background-color: #fde68a;
    }
  }
  .meow {
    width: 90%;
    height: 30vh;
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
    font-size: 12rem;
    filter: invert(1);
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    padding-left: 1vh;
    margin-left: 10%;
  }
  .right-content1 {
    width: 45%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  .kitty2 {
    margin-top: 10vh;
    left: 0px;
  }
`;
```

elements with "behind" classes are the ones that appear differently.

Anyone has any idea how to style them consistently on both browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a css.reset?
A CSS Reset resets all the browser styles

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
       v2.0 | 20110126
       License: none (public domain)
    */
    
    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
    del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
    small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
    b, u, i, center,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
    fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
    article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
    figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
    menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
    time, mark, audio, video {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font: inherit;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
    footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
        display: block;
    }
    body {
        line-height: 1;
    }
    ol, ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
    blockquote, q {
        quotes: none;
    }
    blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
    q:before, q:after {
        content: '';
        content: none;
    }
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
```

Comment: Yes! there are many alternatives. Instead of the code you could share the link of the library so the OP can look its information and maybe install it using whatever tools hes already using in his project

Comment: the link is commented at the top, no?

Comment: True. Didn't see it.